# Why do I have a memory leak here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I do not understand why Instruments/Leaks tells me that there is a memory leak in my viewDidLoad. I do release both objects in dealoc and set them to nil in viewDidUnload. Can someone give me a clue here?

Link to screen-dump from Instruments: http://i26.tinypic.com/28227iw.png

BR
//Christoffer

Comment: I don't know if Instrumens has such an intelligence but the if statement only contains the listOfItems and not the paymentMethods. Is it possible that listOfItems is null but not the Paymentmethods? If yes it would be a leak, but as said, i'm not sure if instrumens analysis this way i did too.

Comment: This is _the_ answer. If paymentMethods is not nil and listOfItems is nil, you just overwrite the value of paymentMethods and lose the reference to the array. Hence, the leak.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Also, the if statement is redundant. You can just send the release message. If it is already nil, you send a message to nil and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do release both objects in dealoc and set them to nil in viewDidUnload

I might be misunderstanding the grammer of the sentence, but
you should release **and** set to nil in **both** dealloc and viewDidUnload.

As a general rule, you should always release and set to nil as a pair unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Not to mention that just releasing an object without setting references to it to nil is plain dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I see the error/flaws in the code that you point out and corrected them. But the result is the same. So how should this be implemented if you want to initialize class objects each time the view loads?

Comment: You should release them in viewUnload and create them in viewLoad

Comment: Ok I got it to work by initializing the NSMutableArray in another way:
This Work:  
self.listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.paymentmethods = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

This does not work:
self.listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];
self.paymentmethods = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];

Do you guys know why the other causes a leak?

Comment: Both of those leak, assuming the properties are retained.